# PHP nested foreach only returning first object

Tags: php, api, foreach

I am programming to an API that lists each taxes under each item instead of providing a summary of all like taxes. Below is the code I'm using.

```
$details = get_invoice_tax_details($k);  // CURLs API and json_decodes the response
$sales_tax = 0;
foreach($details->data->items as $i => $item) {
    foreach($item->taxes as $a => $x) {
        if (strpos($a, "Sales") !== false) {
            $sales_tax = ($sales_tax + $x->tax_amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is an example of the API JSON payload returned to the `$details` object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": {
      "ZgwTzCspyMQjQNQKLcfo5STvRZ": {
        "item_number": "HIP-SLS-6731i",
        "display_order": "1",
        "title": "Hosted IP Seat with Mitel 6731i",
        "description": "",
        "type": "Subscription",
        "category": "Subscription",
        "gl_code": "4130 Hosted Revenue-Asterisk",
        "price": "29.95",
        "quanitity": "13",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "proration": [],
        "tax_method": "Full Tax Rating",
        "taxes": {
          "State Sales Tax": {
            "revenue": "223.85610158525250000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "260.00500",
            "tax_on_tax": "1.44596",
            "tax_type_code": "10101",
            "tax_type_desc": "State Sales Tax",
            "tax_amount": "10.40",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.04",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "12032"
          },
          "County Sales Tax": {
            "revenue": "223.85610158525250000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "260.00484",
            "tax_on_tax": "1.71707",
            "tax_type_code": "20201",
            "tax_type_desc": "County Sales Tax",
            "tax_amount": "12.35",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.0475",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "1625"
          },
          "Ny State Excise Tax": {
            "revenue": "223.85610158525250000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "260.00480",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.90372",
            "tax_type_code": "12780",
            "tax_type_desc": "Ny State Excise Tax",
            "tax_amount": "6.50",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.025",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "12032"
          },
          "Erie Co. 911 Surcharge": {
            "revenue": "48.68335062500000000000",
            "revenue_base": "48.68335062500000000000",
            "tax_on_tax": "0",
            "tax_type_code": "23380",
            "tax_type_desc": "Erie Co. 911 Surcharge",
            "tax_amount": "4.55",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "4.55",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "1625"
          },
          "Federal Universal Service Fund": {
            "revenue": "223.85610158525250000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "78.34964",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.00000",
            "tax_type_code": "03580",
            "tax_type_desc": "Federal Universal Service Fund",
            "tax_amount": "25.86",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.33",
            "percent_taxable": "0.35",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "16"
          },
          "Federal Cost Recovery Fee": {
            "revenue": "223.85610158525250000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "223.85560",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.00000",
            "tax_type_code": "06028",
            "tax_type_desc": "Federal Cost Recovery Fee",
            "tax_amount": "1.86",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.00831",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "16"
          },
          "Federal Cost Recovery Charge": {
            "revenue": "223.85610158525250000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "145.28249",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.00000",
            "tax_type_code": "06080",
            "tax_type_desc": "Federal Cost Recovery Charge",
            "tax_amount": "1.93",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.01331",
            "percent_taxable": "0.65",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "16"
          }
        }
      },
      "yVVSp4QjyUDQb327GsTyDAmAFM": {
        "item_number": "HIP-SLS-6757i",
        "display_order": "2",
        "title": "Hosted IP Seat with Mitel 6757i",
        "description": "",
        "type": "Subscription",
        "category": "Subscription",
        "gl_code": "4130 Hosted Revenue-Asterisk",
        "price": "34.95",
        "quanitity": "1",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "proration": [],
        "tax_method": "Full Tax Rating",
        "taxes": {
          "State Sales Tax": {
            "revenue": "20.094441377692500000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "23.33725",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.12971",
            "tax_type_code": "10101",
            "tax_type_desc": "State Sales Tax",
            "tax_amount": "0.93",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.04",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "12032"
          },
          "County Sales Tax": {
            "revenue": "20.094441377692500000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "23.33747",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.15404",
            "tax_type_code": "20201",
            "tax_type_desc": "County Sales Tax",
            "tax_amount": "1.11",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.0475",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "1625"
          },
          "Ny State Excise Tax": {
            "revenue": "20.094441377692500000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "23.33760",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.08108",
            "tax_type_code": "12780",
            "tax_type_desc": "Ny State Excise Tax",
            "tax_amount": "0.58",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.025",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "12032"
          },
          "Erie Co. 911 Surcharge": {
            "revenue": "4.37006062500000000000",
            "revenue_base": "4.37006062500000000000",
            "tax_on_tax": "0",
            "tax_type_code": "23380",
            "tax_type_desc": "Erie Co. 911 Surcharge",
            "tax_amount": "0.35",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.35",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "1625"
          },
          "Federal Universal Service Fund": {
            "revenue": "20.094441377692500000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "7.03306",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.00000",
            "tax_type_code": "03580",
            "tax_type_desc": "Federal Universal Service Fund",
            "tax_amount": "2.32",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.33",
            "percent_taxable": "0.35",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "16"
          },
          "Federal Cost Recovery Fee": {
            "revenue": "20.094441377692500000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "20.09386",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.00000",
            "tax_type_code": "06028",
            "tax_type_desc": "Federal Cost Recovery Fee",
            "tax_amount": "0.17",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.00831",
            "percent_taxable": "1.00",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "16"
          },
          "Federal Cost Recovery Charge": {
            "revenue": "20.094441377692500000000000000",
            "revenue_base": "13.04132",
            "tax_on_tax": "0.00000",
            "tax_type_code": "06080",
            "tax_type_desc": "Federal Cost Recovery Charge",
            "tax_amount": "0.17",
            "county_name": "ERIE",
            "city_name": "BUFFALO",
            "tax_rate": "0.01331",
            "percent_taxable": "0.65",
            "fee_rate": "0.00",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "14221",
            "zip4": "",
            "tax_authority_id": "16"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am struggling to determine why the code is only coming up with a `$sales_tax` value of 22.75 instead of 24.79. During my debugging, all I can figure is that the second embedded `foreach` loop is only going over the first item and not moving onto the second. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't duplicate it. I'm getting 24.79 -  https://3v4l.org/p6G86

Comment: Add some debugging to your code

Comment: Same here. Using your example API Payload above I get 24.79 as well. Seems ok to me. Are you sure that you are actually getting the expected payload when you call `get_invoice_tax_details`? Or is it returning just the first item?